# copy text from WSL to windows clipboard

Tags: linux, windows, tmux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clipboard

I set up [tmux](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/tmux/) in WSL and I want to improve the integration between them.

How to select text in tmux inside of WSL and copy it to the Windows clipboard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- open the file `~/.tmux.conf` and create it if it does not exist
- enable mouse mode by adding the line `set -g mouse on` (if not, you will have to select the text with `Ctl`+`[`)
- create a key binding to copy the tmux buffer to the windows clipboard:

  `bind -n M-w run -b "tmux show-buffer | clip.exe"`

With this key configuration, you can select text with the mouse and copy it(to the tmux buffer) using `Alt`+`w`. (If you want to select something and don't want it to disappear, press `shift` while letting the mouse button go.) After this, press `Alt`+`w` again in order to copy the tmux buffer to the Windows clipboard.

Comment: `-bash: clip.exe: command not found`

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, if you are using windows terminal, selecting text with the mouse while holding `shift` and copying it with `Ctl` + `Insert` will always just work (even through ssh) and doesn't mess up line breaks.

Comment: This just works! Thanks!